# Javascript Dynamic Function Invocation

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I want to do something kind of Rubyish in Javascript. I'm writing a wrapper around setting DOM element styles. That would go something like (on a per style basis):

```
ele.style.backgroundColor = someSetting
ele.style.padding = anotherSetting
```

What I'd like to do (and I'll use Ruby syntax to illustrate) is:

```
class Element
  def initialize(ele)
    @ele = ele
  end

  def setDOMElementStyle(styleSettings = {})
    styleSettings.each_pair do |styleAttribute, setting|
      @element.style.send(styleAttribute, setting)
  end

  # Other wrapper stuff for elements here
end

element = Element.new document.createElement("div")
element.setDOMElementStyle :width => '60px', :height => '2px', :top => '0px', :left => '0px'
```

In Javascript, I can do this with the dreaded `eval`, but I wondered if there was a neater way to handle it. Here's a hack at it with the evil `eval`.

```
var Element, element;

Element = function() {
  function Element(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }
  Element.prototype.setDOMElementStyle = function(styleSettings) {
    var setting, styleAttribute;

    if (styleSettings == null) {
      styleSettings = {};
    }
    for (setting in styleSettings) {
      styleAttribute = styleSettings[setting];
      eval("@element.style." + styleAttribute + " = " + setting);
    }
  }
}

element = new Element(document.createElement("div"));
element.setDOMElementStyle({
  width: '60px',
  height: '2px',
  top: '0px',
  left: '0px'
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need `eval`, can you just use jQuery and [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)? Or `.style[attr]=val`?

Comment: You already used `[]` to access `styleSettings[setting]`...

Comment: @DaveNewton Pseudo-code for educative purposes. Using tricks is not the right method to learn a language.

Comment: @RobW Not sure why you're telling me that.

Comment: He's clearly trying to port ruby-ish behavior to JS. The way to learn JS is not "using JQUery" (JQuery == JS, but JS != JQuery).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use square braces:

```
element.style[styleAttribute] = setting
```

In JavaScript, every property can also be referred through square braces. Examples:

```
window.location.href === window["location"].href === window["location"]["href"]
    === window.location["href"]
```

Comment: [embarrassed grin] I remembered that some of the DOM objects were simply hostile to accessing as normal indexable objects. Happily, it turns out I was wrong. Thanks!